# How do I split one column in a dataframe into multiple columns based on a defined size

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert  rows in a dataframe which is fixedwidth to a delimited data :

How to achieve this in java/JavaRDD .

Input Dataframe :
df.show()

c0

|WAAAAAAWone|

|QBAAAAAWtwo|

Output : should be pipe(|) delimited .

co  |c1    |  c2

W |AAAAAA|Wone|

Q |BAAAAA|Wtwo|

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `String.substring(int start, int end)`. Here's a working implementation of the method you'd need for this.

```java
public static String parseData(String data) {
    String ret = "c0|c1|c2";

    // Remove edge delimiters
    data = data.replaceAll("\\|", "");

    // Split rows
    String[] rows = data.split("\n");

    // Iterate through each row
    for(String row : rows) {
        // We end up with extra empty strings because of pipe delimiting, skip them
        if("".equals(row)) continue;

        // Check row length, throw exception if incorrect
        if(row.length() != 11) {
            String message = String.format("Row passed to parseData() was the wrong length! Expected 11, got %d", row.length());
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }

        String col1 = row.substring(0,1);  // Get column one (length=1)
        String col2 = row.substring(1,7);  // Get column 2 (length=6)
        String col3 = row.substring(7,11); // Get column 3 (length=4)

        // Add delimited row to return string
        ret += (String.format("\n%s|%s|%s", col1, col2, col3));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I tested it. `parseData("|WAAAAAAWone|\n|QBAAAAAWtwo|")` returns:

```
c0|c1|c2
W|AAAAAA|Wone
Q|BAAAAA|Wtwo
```